# Join all square root expressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Sometimes I observe *Mathematica* produce expressions exactly like the following after a simplification step:

$$\frac{a+\sqrt{-(1-b)}\sqrt{\frac{1}{b-1}}}{\sqrt{c}\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}}$$

Now, any further generic `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` would not do any good any more. One is tempted to use `PowerExpand`, but this would just introduce an annoying `i` term in the numerator, instead of simplifying correctly. Therefore, what I have been doing is typing in simplifications like:

```
/.Sqrt[x_]Sqrt[y_]/(Sqrt[z_]Sqrt[m_])->Sqrt[x y]/Sqrt[z m]//Simplify
```

by hand. This is very annoying. Maybe there is a *Mathematica* function which joins all the square roots in all possible places of an expression together?

**EDIT**
Example code to be simplified:

```
Sqrt[-(1 - b)] Sqrt[1/(b - 1)]
```

Generally, any simplification involving explicitly specifying properties of terms involved does not help really, since the amount of actions is the same as manually correcting the expression. What I am looking for is a function which merges all possible square roots together, regardless of content.

**EDIT2**

Please note the following triviality: a search for a function performing the merging of all square roots in an expression only makes sense if an appropriate branch for the square root functions is chosen so that $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x y}$ is actually true for the expressions in question. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post _Mathematica_ syntax ?

Comment: FullSimplify[
 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b]/(Sqrt[c] Sqrt[d]), {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0}]

Comment: chuy, the aim is to have such a function for arbitrary expressions under the square roots.

Comment: Consider `Sqrt[-2] Sqrt[-2] != Sqrt[4]` and `Sqrt[-3] Sqrt[-1/3] != 1`.

Comment: Holw about `expr //. Sqrt[x_] Sqrt[y_] -> Sqrt[x y]`.

Comment: works well for `Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] c`, but fails with `Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[b]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but the missing of the `PowerContract` function as a build-in is a bit annoying, because such simplification tasks occur quite often.

From an old book (Quantum Methods with Matematica / Springer 1994 / James M. Feagin) I have the following function:

```
PowerContract[expr_] := expr //.
    { m_^q_ n_^q_ :> (m n)^q /; !IntegerQ[m] && !IntegerQ[n], 
      m_^q_ n_^p_ :> (m/n)^q /; q >= 0 && p == -q && 
                                !IntegerQ[m] && !IntegerQ[n]}
```

For example gives

```
Sqrt[-(1 - b)] Sqrt[1/(b - 1)] // PowerContract
```

as result simply 1.

Comment: `Simplify[Sqrt[-(1 - b)] Sqrt[1/(b - 1)], Element[a | b, Integers] && a > 0 && b > 0]` == 1

Answer (score 5):

You have to let Mathematica know that the arguments inside the square roots are positive and real. So you can add the assumptions that `a` and `c` are positive and that `b>1` (so that `b-1` is positive).

```
expr = (a + 3 w Sqrt[-(1 - b)] Sqrt[1/(b - 1)])/(r Sqrt[c] Sqrt[1/c]);
FullSimplify[expr, {a > 0, c > 0, b > 1}]
```

The answer is

```
(a + 3 w)/r
```

Comment: The same simplification is correct also for `b<1`.

Comment: No it doesn't. As wikipedia says: "Because of the discontinuous nature of the square root function in the complex plane, the law √zw = √z√w is in general not true. (Equivalently, the problem occurs because of the freedom in the choice of branch. The chosen branch may or may not yield the equality; in fact, the choice of branch for the square root need not contain the value of √z√w at all, leading to the equality's failure." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root

Comment: Good point. In further discussion, please, choose the appropriate branch for the equality to indeed hold. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not a "canonical" way to do this that holds in all cases. You can see what can happen in J.M.'s answer: when you always allow the simplification, you can get contradictions. In other words, your goal of " a function which merges all possible square roots together, regardless of content" may lead to contradictions, depending on the content.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Then like this: consider the choice of branch to be dynamic and adaptive to any situation such that the equality holds. Exclude cases in which such a branch cannot be found. Btw: the only problem with J.M.'s version, is that it lets spectator factors vanish which do not belong to the square roots being simplified.

Comment: How about this: test for the positivity of the value inside the square root, if that is True, then do the simplification, otherwise do not.

Answer (score 4):

My attempt, using a combination of replacement rules, `Factor` and `PowerExpand`

```
simple = PowerExpand[Factor //@ #] //. 
 {1/Sqrt[x_] :> Sqrt[1/x], Sqrt[x_] Sqrt[y_] :> Sqrt[x y]} &;
```

Testing on various expressions found among the comments:

```
exprs = {Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[b],
   Sqrt[-(1 - b)] Sqrt[1/(b - 1)],
   (a + 3 w Sqrt[-(1 - b)] Sqrt[1/(b - 1)])/(r Sqrt[c] Sqrt[1/c]),
   Sqrt[1/(1 - s^2)] Sqrt[s^2 - s^4],
   Sqrt[-1 + (1 + 1/b^2) Cosh[s]^2] Sqrt[1/(b^2 - (1 + b^2) Cosh[s]^2)],
   Sqrt[-1 + (1 + 1/b^2) Cosh[s]^2] Sqrt[1/(b^2 - (1 + b^2) Cosh[s]^2)] Sech[s]^2};

simple /@ exprs
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[a/b], 1, (a + 3 w)/r, -s, I/b, (I Sech[s]^2)/b}
> ```

Comment: Fails on `Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[5]`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
expr = (a + 3 w Sqrt[-(1 - b)] Sqrt[1/(b - 1)])/(r Sqrt[c] Sqrt[1/c]);

Simplify[expr, Positive[Cases[expr, Power[stuff_, 1/2 | -1/2] :> stuff, ∞]]]
   (a + 3 w)/r
```

Comment: Good idea, but now this function gives for `expr=Sqrt[1/(1 - s^2)] Sqrt[s^2 - s^4]` the unhandy result `Abs[s]`. Is there a way to merge square roots but to retain their structure?

Comment: That'd take a bit more work...

Comment: Just added `/. Abs[xx_] -> Sqrt[xx^2]` to your expression. :] Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops! Something going wrong here: `Sqrt[-1 + (1 + 1/b^2) Cosh[s]^2] Sqrt[1/(b^2 - (1 + b^2) Cosh[s]^2)]` complains about contradictory assumtions and gives `I/b`. But more importantly `Sqrt[-1 + (1 + 1/b^2) Cosh[s]^2] Sqrt[1/(b^2 - (1 + b^2) Cosh[s]^2)]
  Sech[s]^2` also complains but gives the same `I/b`! So `Sech[s]^2` vanishes from the expression...