# Simplify fraction of Gamma functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

From evaluating products of Wigner 6-j symbols I end up with expressions containing fractions of Gamma functions. For example,

$\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma (2 N)}{\Gamma (2 N+3)}},$

where $N$ is a positive integer.  This expression can be simplified to

$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{N (N+1) (2 N+1)}}.$

However, when executing

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[Gamma[2*N]/Gamma[3 + 2*N]],{N >= 1, N \[Element] Integers}]
```

the unaltered expression containing the Gamma functions is returned. Funny enough, running FullSimplify on the inverse, that is,

```
FullSimplify[(Sqrt[Gamma[2*N]/Gamma[3 + 2*N]])^(-1),{N >= 1, N \[Element] Integers}]
```

does return

```
2*Sqrt[NN*(1 + NN)*(1 + 2*NN)]
```

However, as my expressions are more complicated than the example given here, simplifying the reciprocal is not an option for me. How can I make mathematica simplify this fractions of factorials?

P.S. I tried the rule suggested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120560) answer, but had no success.

Comment: Try: `FullSimplify[
 Sqrt[Gamma[2*n]/Gamma[3 + 2*n]] // FunctionExpand, {n >= 1, 
  n ∈ Integers}]`

Comment: dont use capital `N` for your own symbol by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `FunctionExpand`:

```
FunctionExpand[Sqrt@(Gamma[2 N]/Gamma[3 + 2 N])]

(* 1/2 Sqrt[1/(N (1 + N) (1 + 2 N))] *)
```

**Edited:**

```
Simplify[Simplify[Sqrt[Gamma[2 n]]/Sqrt[Gamma[3 + 2 n]],
{n >= 1, n ∈ Integers}] // FunctionExpand, {n >= 1, n ∈ Integers}]
```

> $$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \left(2 n^2+3 n+1\right)}}$$

Comment: Thanks, that'a a nice function to remember. Do you known how to get the same result when the square root is in the nominator and denominator, e.g., `FunctionExpand[Sqrt[Gamma[2*NN]]/Sqrt[Gamma[3 + 2*NN]]]` does not simplify.

Comment: Found it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51060/54889)